# Jitter sensitive points in a PostGIS view

Tags: postgis

I have sensitive location data that we want to visualize without giving away location. Clients wants points jittered everytime they are accessed. What I would like to do is store actual location, but in a view, create a geom column based on jittered coordinate and hid the real location. Is this actually possible in PostGIS? I want to feed the view to GeoServer, so it has to appear as geom.

Why jitter points? Well frankly I would rather aggregate to say census meshblocks, but they don't want any aggregation and significant no. of mesh blocks with multiple points.

Comment: You must not serve a different random location on each query otherwise it is *trivial to reverse the original location* by just making a couple of queries and averaging the coordinates. Better snap coordinates to a fixed grid or choose their random location *once*.

Comment: Make sure your clients understand that *actual* location intelligence has a higher level entropy above a mere coordinate reference: its context. A simple, constructed example: no matter the jitter, if I knew what to look for, I could still infer that you're at the casino gambling, rather than attending therapy. The difference to a gridded aggregation is then that the grid can be large enough to loose that context while maintaining aggregated intelligence, whereas increasing jitter on locations completely erases intelligence (i.e. no difference to randomly synthesizing points on a map).

Comment: They want to do a "double jitter" which is what another organization dealing with same data (soil chemistry) use. To my mind is vulnerable to same inspection but I havent tried to demonstrate that. My first issue is whether you can create geometry on the fly that geoserver can use.

Comment: A *View* is a *stored query* which gets executed each time you access the *View*; GeoServer supports *Views* natively. No problem with that.

Answer (score 7):

I would use [`ST_Translate`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Translate.html), generating random points with the PostgreSQL `random` function. Assuming your goemetry is a point, is projected, and the projection uses metres, to randomly jitter it by ±5 metres in the x and y dimensions, do `ST_Translate(geom, random() * 10 - 5, random() * 10 - 5)`.

Each time the view is queried, the random jitter will change. You could work out the original point from this, if you observe multiple changes and note where the centre appears to be. So you could instead do the offset once, if you use a materialised view instead. There are other options too, depending on how sensitive the original point location is. (I'm assuming not that sensitive, or there a) wouldn't be a map, or b) they should accept using census meshblocks.)

Comment: So I gather from comments, that generating geom on fly is indeed doable in Postgis?

Comment: @Scaddenp of course.

Answer (score 5):

When you observe repeated random offsets, you can deduce the original position as the center of the resulting cloud.

To remove information, use [ST_ReducePrecision](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ReducePrecision.html) to round coordinates to the specified grid:

```
SELECT ST_ReducePrecision(geom, 1000) FROM MyTable;
```

(If you do not want that grid to become visible, you can still add a random offset afterwards.)

Comment: Actually, I rather like the idea of using the centroid of enclosing census meshblock (pre-calculate) and then jitter on that. What they want to avoid is making the property that sample was taken from visible. Meshblocks work better than grid as they change in size in rural areas where properties are larger.

Comment: In that case, look at https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeneratePoints.html to generate a random point(s) within a geometry.

Comment: Thanks very much, that is an excellent suggestion.